# Codeigniter and Ajax combination

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I have this jquery script that invokes a controller function, say my base url is **www.mydomain.com/controller/main** and I have this form that sends data via ajax to my processing function on the same controller like **myOtherController/process** wouldn't that append to the base url if my url is now **www.mydomain.com/controller/myotherfunction** if I do my script like this..

```
$.post('myOtherController/process',postData, function(data){});
```

wouldn't be the url be now **www.mydomain.com/controller/myotherfunction/myOtherController/process** if I do the script above?... I've already tried that and it worked, but I can't seem to understand why it worked.. can someone clear things up for me?...

Comment: can you show your config base_url form config.php file

Comment: it blank didn't put anything

Comment: better to put base_url in config, complete solution find in answer

Comment: its blank already don't need to put it up

Answer (score 0):

first set site base_url in config.php now in your view before calling ajax script create an javascript variable name base_url

**view calling ajax**

```
<script> 
     var base_url = "<?=base_url()?>";
     var ajax_url = base_url+'/myOtherController/process';
     $.post(ajax_url,postData, function(data){});
</script>
```

example 2

```
<script> 
     var base_url = "<?=base_url()?>";
</script>
<script src="you_js_file.js"></script>
```

in your js file you can call globally defined base_url

```
var ajax_url = base_url+'/myOtherController/process';
$.post(ajax_url,postData, function(data){});
```

Comment: as what i know, if base url config in the config file is left blank... it uses a default or something... but can a php tag be included on a .js file?

Comment: @lemoncodes You have to set `base_url` it inline, then you can use it in your javascript file.

Comment: you have to set in your config.php, if short hand tags or not enable in your php then use <?echo base_url()?>

Comment: if i can display the value of base_url() in a simple .php file does it go to when doing it inline on .js file?

Comment: yes it will be global base url for your all js files but it should be declared before all js files, check other example in above answer

Comment: Doesn't base_url() also return the trailing slash? Isn't this actually what you want?  

    var ajax_url = base_url+'myOtherController/process';

Comment: Already done those but i dont get why u need to declare a base url in config file?...

Comment: in old version of CI developer need to put base url in config file, just found since version 2.0.0 it will automatically guess what it should be, well in my point of view you should provide base url